# How to create a scrolling image gallery in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, nsarray

In my app, I have 5 images, and 2 buttons(next and previous).
I have stored those images in an array.
When next button is pressed, I want to remove the current image and display the next image, and for previous button, it is vice versa.
I have done this using the code.

```
-(void)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    if (i < (array.count-1))
    {
        i=i+1;
     imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

-(void)previousButton:(id)sender
{
    if(i >= 1)
    {
        i=i-1;
        imageView.image=[images objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Now, my doubt is, when the image changes, there happens no animation, simple the next image replaces the previous image.
But, my request is when I click the button, the previous button should decrease by the width and move out of the imageView and the next image should come inside the imageView gradually like this

[image]

Comment: No, friends I dont need this much animation, those 5 images should be filled like a cylinder, it should roatte, like a datePicker

Answer (score 0):

I understand it and it looks like you would need some custom animation, check out [it has various animation and u can use anyone you like](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are just simply assigning image to the imageview. that's why there is no animation. For this animation, you can use the below library

http://code4app.net/ios/iCarousel-for-Cover-Flow/4f87d2db06f6e79d32000000

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a cover flow effect. Try browsing iCarousel. Try link below, it provides great options for different style

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel

Answer (score 0):

use iCarousel .. in this you will have @ 7 types of animation. if you don't want to use 3rd party code. Better option is fade-out current image and fade-in new image.